# How to debug gunicorn failure issues? (Worker failed to boot)

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I have a Django web application that uses Gunicorn and runs good locally, but when I deploy app on EC2, I see that Gunicorn is failing:

```
 $ gunicorn_django -b 127.0.0.1:8000 --settings=myapp.settings.dev --debug --log-level info
 2012-09-16 17:39:24 [28333] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.14.6
 2012-09-16 17:39:24 [28333] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (28333)
 2012-09-16 17:39:24 [28333] [INFO] Using worker: sync
 2012-09-16 17:39:24 [28336] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 28336
 2012-09-16 17:39:24 [28336] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 28336)
 2012-09-16 17:39:24 [28333] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
 2012-09-16 17:39:24 [28333] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I tried logging with `--spew` but it keeps on running and no error is shown.

How can I debug this issue?

Answer (score 46):

Try running with `--preload` as an argument to `gunicorn_django` - it should show you the error the workers are having when starting. See [this bug](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/338#issuecomment-7425197)

Comment: I have been try to debug my service for hours, you just saved my day!

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 29):

You need `--debug --log-level debug`

Comment: --debug is deprecated in gunicorn 19.0. See http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/news.html#id28.

Comment: updated link for deprecated is: http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/2014-news.html#id7

Answer (score 7):

In my case I had to run `gunicorn_django --bind example.com:8001` from the same folder as my manage.py file.