# gunicorn fails to start when trying to start

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I am manually starting nginx/gunicorn via command like:

```
sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf; sudo /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c /home/user/virtualenv/gunicorn_config.py mydjangoproject.wsgi;
```

I've triple checked the paths too, but it appears it cannot find my django project (`mydjangoproject`) when I execute this command above.

I doubled checked `sys.path` and it does include my projects path (so my project is in the `pythonpath`)

I'm getting output like:

```
[3207] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
[3207] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8001 (3207)
[3207] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3212
[ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named mydjangoproject.wsgi
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

`Nginx` is starting fine here, its `gunicorn` which seems to be failing to identify my django project.

Can anyone see what may be going wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think you should be starting gunicorn with sudo. And I also think you'll need to pass the full path to your WSGI file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to user `Mik.ro` for their advice on this post:
[How to debug gunicorn failure issues?(Worker failed to boot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449172/how-to-debug-gunicorn-failure-issuesworker-failed-to-boot)

You need to execute this where `manage.py` is located